# Filter an array on basis of given array in efficient way

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

my problem is that, I have to filter an array of arrays (in javascript) on basis of a given array. The structure of array to be search is like this,

```
var arrayToSearchUpon [
['t1','t2','t4','t7'],
['t1','t2','t8','t5'],
['t9','t4']
....//so on
];
```

and input array will be like this

```
var arrayInputFilterWith = ['t1','t2'];
```

And result should be like this

```
[['t1','t2','t4','t7'],['t1','t2','t8','t5'],...//all arrays having t1 & t2 elements]
Right
```

now am doing all this in brute force manner i.e. comparing all elements of input with all elements of search array, but running out of performance. Would like to know if there is any better solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Right now using this way,

```
arrayToFilter = arrayToFilter.filter(function (element) {
            return utilservice.union(filterWith, element).length == element.length;
          });

//union function give union of two arrays
utilservice.union = function (arr1, arr2) {
      var arr = arr1.concat(arr2)
      return arr.filter(function (val, index) {
        return arr.indexOf(val) === index;
      });
    }
```

Comment: I think I'm probably missing something, but I don't see how those results should be obtained from the shown input (`arrayToSearchUpon`).

Comment: @DavidThomas, first array is filter array. And second one is array of arrays. I need to filter second array and get all those array elements which contain all elements of first array i.e. filter array

Comment: Right but based on input shown the output has different sub arrays is the point. It is a bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can preprocess data to filter in an efficient way, you can loop over arrays in a brute force. Then store in a map such that `t1 -> 0,2`, `t2 -> 0,2`, `t3 -> 1,2` and so on.

Then run the query in `O(d)` which `d` is the longest map for an element.

Comment: cool, but final array may contain duplicate elements. Is there any way to prevent that or I need to run a filter for this

Comment: @PiyushSharma why duplicate elements?

Comment: bcoz for t1->0,2 & for t2 -> 0,2 its duplicating 0,2

Comment: @PiyushSharma ohhh. Ok. this duplication helps for efficiency. As you know, these two are not in the same way.

Comment: @PiyushSharma my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which will break as soon as match is found

```js
var matches = ['t1', 't2'];
var data = [
  ['t1', 't2', 't4'], //match
  ['t9', 't2', 't4'], // no match
  ['t2', 't3', 't1']  // match
];
var res = data.filter(arr => matches.every(e => arr.includes(e)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Comment: I think you did not get the question. I'm not looking for how to do it but for how to do it efficiently. that's the almost same thing am doing right now

Comment: @PiyushSharma not really because `every()` doesn't need to look through every element of sub array whereas your `filter()` approach does. If conditions are met in early indicies it will `break` and ignore remaining elements in array